# Find result then range and copy

Tags: function, excel, lookup, vba

I'm having some trouble trying to make a function that acts like vlookup but returns a range rather than a cell

The data to search through looks like this

[image: lookup]

Sometimes there is a space separating sometimes not
What I would like to do is to look up 16 from my main page and return all the values in that range.

[image: main]

the code I currently am using will only return the first line in a messagebox

```
Public Function findrulepos(target) As Range    
    Dim ruleStart, ruleEnd, ruleEnd2 As String       
    Dim RuleRange As Range
    'Dim ruleEnd As Range

    MaxRule = 100000
    MaxRow = 100000

    Set target = Sheets("main").Range("E2")

    Sheets("ResRules").Select

    For i = 3 To MaxRow
        If CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResRules").Range("A" & i).Value) = _
        CStr(target.Value) Then
            ruleStart = _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ResRules").Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Text

            Exit For
         Else
         End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand your requirement or what the code is doing. `findrulepos` is a function. Where are you returning value to it? You have declated `Target` in the function. Why are you resetting it by using this `Set target = Sheets("main").Range("E2")`? What are the three variables `ruleStart, ruleEnd, ruleEnd2` supposed to do? Would be better if you attached a screenshot for a `Before` and `After` scenario.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - screen shots added. sorry for not explaining this better.

Comment: @pnuts Yes ruleEnd 2 is redundant. left there from something else I was doing. but you have the gist of what I would like to do. Is it possible ?

Comment: What is your search criteria? I mean how would the code identify which block you want?

Comment: @SiddharthRout the search criteria is  the number in column A.

Comment: Is there a specific need to use VBA? Seems to me that you could add a formula to column C that repeats the line numbers from col A so that all rows in a "group" have the same number. Then you could use vlookup more effectively (e.g. to find the row with the first occurrence of "16" and copy consecutive rows until the number changes to "17"). Or more helpfully you could probably create a pivot table from columns B and C, using col C as a filter.

Comment: @MattClarke - thanks for the suggestion. I had tried something similar but found that as the search range has nearly 100,000 rows that the formula was taking way too long and causing Excel to freeze/crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that the numeric group labels in col A are sequential, then I think this will achieve what you need:

1. Enter the numeric label you are wanting to extract (16 in your example) into cell E1
2. Note that `=MATCH(E1,A:A,0)` gives us the row number where group 16
   starts, which is the first row we want to copy. Similarly,
   `=MATCH(E1+1,A:A,0)` gives us the row number where group 17 starts,
   which is one row below the last row we want to copy. (Unfortunately
   that's not true for the very last group of code, but to rectify that
   you just need to add a dummy number at the very bottom of the data
   in col A.)
3. Enter the formula `=IF(ROW()+MATCH(E$1,A:A,0)-1<MATCH(E$1+1,A:A,0),INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E$1,A:A,0)+ROW()-1),"")` in F1. That should copy the first value of the selected code block -- `[DO] ADD TO QUEUE P` in your example.
4. Copy F1 down as many rows as the largest code block is likely to be.
5. The one problem with that is that it will put `0` whenever it copies a blank row. So you have to explicitly check for that case, e.g. by changing the formula in F1 to `=IF(ROW()+MATCH(E$1,A:A,0)-1<MATCH(E$1+1,A:A,0),IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E$1,A:A,0)+ROW()-1)),"",INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(E$1,A:A,0)+ROW()-1)),"")`

Comment: looks great. the only problem is Column A is not guaranteed to be in Numerical order or to have a sequential order wither. so could be missing numbers and out of order.

Comment: So you should be able to tweek my formula to look for a non-blank value in col A rather than the next sequential number. Alternatively, add a (hidden) column C with `C1=A1` and `C2=if(isblank(A2),C1,A2)` (and copy down). Having those repeated values rather than blanks may make it easier to build a formula that extracts just one code group.